# Intel SMBus UNCLAIMED

Tags: 12.04, drivers, smbus

My laptop running `Ubuntu 12.04.3` has this SMBus according to `lspci`:

```
SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

`lshw` command shows it as unclaimed. Which driver is needed to activate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct driver would be i2c-i801, of which Intel states that it's compatible with the Series 6 PCH: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/busses/i2c-i801

In recent kernels (2.6.12 and later), the option is in drivers/i2c/busses. From  2.6.0 through 2.6.11, the driver was present, but considered experimental.

To find out if the module is present on your system, use `modinfo i2c_i801`. If the module is found, try to load it using `modprobe i2c_i801`.

Comment: @KasiyA Please open a new question